# Replicating curl command in babaska

Tags: curl, clojure, github-api, babashka

I have the following curl command from the github api that I wish to replicate in babashka:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/user/repos \
  -d '{"name":"test"}'
```

Currently, I have tried:

```clj
(ns bb-test
 (require [environ.core :refer [env]]
          [babashka.curl :as curl])

(def url "https://api.github.com/user/repos")
(def token (env :token))
(def headers {"Accept" "application/json" "Authorization" (str "Bearer " token)})
(def body "{'name:' 'test'}")

(curl/post url {:headers headers :body body})
```

I get back a 400 http status code. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you try it with the same spelling of `Authorization`?

Comment: @DaveNewton, ah yes sorry that was a typo - I have tried that

Comment: In the bash syntax `'{"name":"test"}'`, bash isn't being given something it's expected to parse as a dictionary/map type before handoff to curl; instead, everything except those outer single quotes is _an exact string_ to send over the wire. The expectation for your Clojure code is the same: the content of your body isn't parsed by Clojure locally, it's sent over the wire exactly as-is and parsed by the remote server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bash example, you're sending a body with `{"name":"test"}` as the literal data sent over the wire to the server.

With the babashka example, you're sending a body with `{'name:' 'test'}` as the literal data sent over the wire to the server.

Only one of these things is valid JSON.

The Clojure syntax to describe a literal string containing data `{"name":"test"}` is `"{\"name\":\"test\"}"`, so the smallest change is to modify the line where you run `def body`:

```clj
(def body "{\"name\":\"test\"}")
```

---

Alternately, you can use a JSON library such as Cheshire to encode a native Clojure structure into a JSON string:

```clj
(ns bb-test
 (require [environ.core :refer [env]]
          [cheshire.core :as json]
          [babashka.curl :as curl])

(def url "https://api.github.com/user/repos")
(def token (env :token))
(def headers {"Accept" "application/json"
              "Authorization" (str "Bearer " token)})
(def body {"name" "test"})

(curl/post url {:headers headers
                :body (json/generate-string body)})
```

Comment: Thank you for this - makes a lot of sense! Appreciate your help :)